# Can you upload at PYPI with multiple users

Tags: python, upload, package, pypi

I saw someone mentioning ACLs but that might refer only to the old PYPI and the new portal does not have this functionality? But maybe its still possible somehow to grant other users the right to upload a specific package?

If yes: how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way as before: an owner of the project logins, goes to "Manage" command, at the left sidebar selects "Collaborators" and adds new owners or maintainers, manage/delete existing collaborators.

Example: I'm a non-owning maintainer at https://pypi.org/project/Cheetah3/

Comment: i could have sworn that this link wasnt there a few days before .. :/